# How can i read a string from a file which is before a integer

Tags: c, string, file

I have this text file:

```
2 6
99 100 14 15 1 4 29 43 15 15
31 24 2 0 2 0 2 0 12 12
1 5 2 6 3 50 2 0 1 100
31 24 2 0 2 0 2 0 12 12
99 100 14 15 1 4 29 43 15 15
Lucky 0 0 100 100
James 2 0 100 100
Jerry 2 4 100 100
Cristofor 0 2 100 100
Chris 2 3 100 100
Miclaus 2 1 100 100
```

I want to read all data in multiple structures.
This is my code: I read first 6 lines and i want to read next 6 and put every word in variables. I don t know how to read that string.

```
void citireDate(){
char c;
FILE *f;
f = fopen("nume.in","r");
fscanf(f,"%d", &R);
fscanf(f,"%d", &P);
for(int i=1;i <= 2*R+1 ; i++)
    for(int j=1;j <= 2*R+1; j++){
        fscanf(f,"%d",&ghetar[i][j].inaltime);
        fscanf(f,"%d",&ghetar[i][j].manusi);
}

for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){

//here i have to read that string
    fscanf(f,"%d",&spiridusi[i].x);
    fscanf(f,"%d",&spiridusi[i].y);
    fscanf(f,"%d",&spiridusi[i].hp);
    fscanf(f,"%d",&spiridusi[i].stamina);

}


fclose(f);
}
```

How can i read that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just read all the line in one `fscanf(f, "%s %d %d %d %d\n", ...);`

```
for(int i=1;i<=6;i++) {
  fscanf(f, "%s %d %d %d %d\n",
         &spiridusi[i].?????,
         &spiridusi[i].x,
         &spiridusi[i].y,
         &spiridusi[i].hp,
         &spiridusi[i].stamina);
}
```

Or course I suppose there is no space in the string before the 4 integers

It is strange the first indexes are always 1, I think they must be 0 in all the *for* (except if you have a good reason to start by 1)

Comment: Ah ok, warning the first index in the vectors/arrays is 0 rather 1, you start by 1 in your _for_